# How do I pass a block and an initial argument to each in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I use `data-tip` for every HTML element to show a tooltip if it has this property.

Since

```
data_tip: "a message for you"
```

looks much nicer than

```
:"data-tip" => "an other message for rudi"
```

I convert '_' to '-' wherever I am responsible for that.

For my `simple navigation gem` menu I found a nice recursive solution:

```
cleanup=Proc.new do |item|
  cleanup_hash item.html_options #<- this does the '_' -> '-'
  item.sub_navigation.items.each(&cleanup) if item.sub_navigation
end
navigation.primary_navigation.items.each(&cleanup)
```

This works great, but, what if I want to print out the nesting level? Where do I put the starting '0'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`curry`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Proc.html#method-i-curry)

```
cleanup=Proc.new do |depth=0, item|
  cleanup_hash item.html_options #<- this does the '_' -> '-'
  item.sub_navigation.items.each(&cleanup.curry[depth + 1]) if item.sub_navigation
end
navigation.primary_navigation.items.each(&cleanup)
```

What curry does:

> A curried proc receives some arguments. If a sufficient number of
>   arguments are supplied, it passes the supplied arguments to the
>   original proc and returns the result. Otherwise, returns another
>   curried proc that takes the rest of arguments.

Comment: curry? like 'salt', 'pepper', or 'chilly'? (ruby names!). Ok needed here - but a good canditate to make code unreadable, isnt it?

Comment: No, Curry like Haskell. [Haskell Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry).

Comment: oh, I am a bit smarter now; Lambda calculus :-/, may I sleep a night or two over deep theory?